# Opposite Clifford-Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, clifford-algebras

for a symmetric bilinearform $\beta$ on a $\mathbb{K}$-vectorspace $V$ the associated Clifford Algebra $Cl(\beta)$ is the associative algebra with unit subject to the relations $$v\cdot v=\beta(v,v)\cdot 1\qquad\forall v\in V.$$It is then often said that $Cl(-\beta)$ is isomorphic to the opposite Algebra $Cl(\beta)^\text{op}$. Why is that?

Cheers, Robert

Comment: The opposite algebra of an algebra is build by the same elements and the same addition, and the multiplication is the same, but in swapped order.

Comment: I know what the opposite of an algebra is. I want to know why $Cl(-\beta)\cong Cl(\beta)^\text{op}$.

Comment: I don't have an answer, so I'll just make the observation that in the case of an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space where $\beta$ is positive definite, the isomorphism can't take vectors to vectors, because the square of a vector is negative in $Cl(-\beta)$ but positive in $Cl(\beta)^{op}$.

Comment: I agree on that. In a book i use quite a lot (Budinich, Trautman: "The spinorial chessboard"), which i believe doesn't do stupid mistakes it says the following: The injection $\iota:V\hookrightarrow Cl(\beta)^\text{op}$ is a Clifford map of $(V,−\beta)$ and then extends to the desired Isomorphism $Cl(-\beta)\cong Cl(\beta)^\text{op}$. However, $\iota(v)^2=\beta(v,v)$ so $\iota$ is a Clifford map of $(V,\beta)$, not $(V,-\beta)$... i don't get it.

Comment: Now i'm really starting to believe the claim to be wrong. For instance, if $V=\mathbb{R}$ and $\beta(x,y)=-xy$ we see that $Cl(\beta)^\text{op}=\mathbb{C}^\text{op}=\mathbb{C}$ is not isomorphic to $Cl(-\beta)$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the product $$(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac+bd,ad+bc).$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, care is needed! We need the right notion of "op", for behold
$Cl(1) \simeq \mathbb{R}^2 \not\simeq \mathbb{C} \simeq  Cl(-1)$, which as algebras are both commutative!

Over $\mathbb{R}$, the Clifford algebras arise naturally in the braided symmetric monoidal category of $\mathbb{Z}/2$-graded vector spaces, or ["super-vector spaces"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_vector_space) ([alternatively...](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/super+vector+space)), as (super-)tensor products of the basic algebras $\mathbb{R}[\varepsilon]$ and $\mathbb{R}[i]$, where $\varepsilon$ and $i$ denote *odd* roots of $\pm 1$.

As with ordinary vector spaces, there is an isomorphism
$$ \tau : A \otimes B \to B \otimes A, $$
and you need something like this to make an algebra of $A\otimes B$, given the algebra structures on $A$ and $B$ separately:
$$ (A\otimes B) \otimes (A\otimes B) \overset{A\otimes \tau\otimes B}\longrightarrow (A\otimes A)\otimes(B\otimes B) \overset{m_A\otimes m_B}\longrightarrow A \otimes B .$$
Figuring out different ways to define $\tau$ can be confusing at first, but you'll get used to it.

Now, in ordinary vector spaces, the "opposite" product $m^{op}$ is derived from $m$ by pre-composition with the transpose on $A\otimes A$:
$$ m^{op} = A\otimes A \overset{\tau}\to A\otimes A \overset{m}\to A, $$
and the same expression is the "right way" to define the opposite multiplication on a superalgebra; only the $\tau$ means something slightly different for superspaces vs. for ordinary vector spaces.

So, the exercises to start with are to understand $\tau$, and then to verify that $m_{-1}^{op} = m_1 $ and vice-versa --- or, understanding $\tau$, to carry-out the calculation over clifford algebras in full generality.

My favourite reference for superalgebras is [Trimble's notes](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/trimble/superdivision.html), but now you've read the words "symmetric" and "braided" and "monoidal" together, you can go on digging. Have fun!

Comment: Your favorite reference for superalgebras is...what?

Comment: Sorry, Trimble's notes on superdivision algebras; http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/trimble/superdivision.html
I can't remember why, but it made an impression. (when I wrote the answer I didn't have 10 rep yet, so it wouldn't let me include a third link)

Comment: No problem.  I took the liberty of editing it into your response (should be visible once the edit is "peer reviewed").  Thanks!

Comment: Do I unterstand you correctly that the reason for my confusion is that i am using the "wrong" definition of $Cl(\beta)^\text{op}$?

Answer (score 0):

There are different conventions for Clifford algebras, which is confusing.
If I understand your question correctly.
If the  convention for the bilinear form is

$
v . v=\beta(v,v)\cdot 1\qquad\forall v\in V
$

then the algebra is denoted as $\mathcal{Cl}_{p,q}$.

In the opposite convention

$v . v= - \beta(v,v)\cdot 1\qquad\forall v\in V
$

it is equivalent to the algebra $\mathcal{Cl}_{q,p}$.